# Jquery add checked radio parent div class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have one question about add class.

I have created this [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/LGLrBo) from *codepen.io* .

In this demo you can see there are tree radio button. When you click blue button after checked radio button then the .checkedWrap text will be changing.

I want to add also some class in this `.checkedWrap` .

So when you click

```
<div class="row demo">
    <input type="radio" id="checked" name="checkit" class="cbx hidden"/>
    <label for="checked" class="lbl"></label>TExt 1
    <div id="1" class="addthisClassone"></div>
  </div>
```

there is also `<div id="1" class="addthisClassone"></div>` i want to add `addthisClassone` from the `.checkedWrap` also like this:

```
 <div class="checkedWrap addthisClassone"></div>
 <div class="checkedWrap addthisClasstwo"></div>
 <div class="checkedWrap addthisClasstree"></div>
```

How can i do that after clicking blue button. Anyone can help me in this regard.

CSS

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="checkedWrap addthisClassone"></div>
   <div class="checkList">
    <div class="row demo">
    <input type="radio" id="checked" name="checkit" class="cbx hidden"/>
    <label for="checked" class="lbl"></label>TExt 1
    <div id="1" class="addthisClassone"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row demo">
    <input type="radio" id="checked1" name="checkit" class="cbx hidden"/>
    <label for="checked1" class="lbl"></label>fdsaf asdfasd fasdf
     <div id="2" class="addthisClasstwo"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" id="unchecked_disabled" class="cbx hidden" disabled/>
    <label for="unchecked_disabled" class="lbl">fdsafasf</label>
     <div id="3" class="addthisClasstree"></div>
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="Click">Click ok to add checked radio text from the red div</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('body').on('click', '.Click', function(){
      var checked_radio_text = $('input[name=checkit]:checked').parent().text();
      $('.checkedWrap').text(checked_radio_text);
  });
```

Comment: Your question is more mess than question to be honest, it hurts my brain trying to read it `:/`. What class do you want to add when you do what?

Comment: Try adding this `$("#checkedWrap").addClass("addthisClasstree");` inside your jquery

Comment: @LittlePhild this is not a solution if i use `$(this).addClass("addthisClasstree");` then it will add just `addthisClasstree` but there are also `addthisClasstwo` and `addthisClassone`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to add an extra general `class` instead of `ids` and **[data attributes](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** to store the classes you want to change on every radio button, check the example bellow.

**Note :** To add class you can use **[addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/)** function but that will append classes so every time you click new class will be added, you could reset class attribute using **[removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)** on every click and add default class `checkedWrap` plus the new class :

```
$('.checkedWrap').removeClass().addClass('checkedWrap '+additional_class);
```

Hope this helps.

---

### Snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.Click', function(){
      var checked_radio_text = $('input[name=checkit]:checked').parent().text();
      var additional_class = $('input[name=checkit]:checked').parent().find('.global-class').data('additional-class');
    
      $('.checkedWrap').text(checked_radio_text);
      $('.checkedWrap').removeClass().addClass('checkedWrap '+additional_class);
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
   width:400px;
   height:auto;
   box-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 13px 13px 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 13px 13px 0;
  -moz-box-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 13px 13px 0;
   margin:0px auto;
   margin-top:10px;
}
.checkedWrap {
   width:100% !important;
   float:left;
   padding:15px;
   background-color:#b71c1c;
   box-sizing:border-box;
}
.checkList {
   width:100%;
   padding:10px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   float:left;
}

.lbl {
   float:left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 34px;
  background: #898989;
  border-radius: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  
}

.lbl:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: -2px;
  top: -5px;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  content: '';
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.lbl:active:after { transform: scale(1.15, 0.85); }

.cbx:checked ~ label { background: #6fbeb5; }

.cbx:checked ~ label:after {
  left: 20px;
  background: #179588;
}

.cbx:disabled ~ label {
  background: #d5d5d5;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.cbx:disabled ~ label:after { background: #bcbdbc; }

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.demo { 
   padding:30px;
   width:100%; 
   overflow:hidden;
   padding:5px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   text-indent:10px;
}

.hidden { display: none; }

.Click {
   float:left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  height:30px;
   background-color:#0288d1;
   color:#ffffff;
   width:100%;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   text-align:center;
   line-height:30px;
   font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
   cursor:pointer;
}

.addthisClassone {
   width:10px;
   height:10px;
   background-color:blue;
}
.addthisClasstwo {
   background-color:green;
    width:10px;
   height:10px;
}
.addthisClasstree {
   background-color:black;
    width:10px;
   height:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="checkedWrap addthisClassone"></div>
   <div class="checkList">
    <div class="row demo">
    <input type="radio" id="checked" name="checkit" class="cbx hidden"/>
    <label for="checked" class="lbl"></label>TExt 1
    <div data-additional-class='addthisClassone' class="global-class"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row demo">
    <input type="radio" id="checked1" name="checkit" class="cbx hidden"/>
    <label for="checked1" class="lbl"></label>fdsaf asdfasd fasdf
    <div data-additional-class='addthisClasstwo' class="global-class"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" id="unchecked_disabled" class="cbx hidden"/>
    <label for="unchecked_disabled" class="lbl">fdsafasf</label>
     <div data-additional-class='addthisClasstree' class="global-class"></div>
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="Click">Click ok to add checked radio text from the red div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a class with JavaScript, you can use jQuery, it has a function for that.

Check [addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/). It adds a new class to a particular jQuery DOM Element.

Answer (score 0):

> `addClass` Adds the specified class(es) to each element in the set of
>   matched elements.

Try out this

```
    $('body').on('click', '.Click', function(){
      var checked_radio_text = $('input[name=checkit]:checked').parent().text();
      $('.checkedWrap').text(checked_radio_text);
      $("#checkedWrap").addClass("addthisClasstree");
  });
```

Comment: this is not a solution. You are adding just `addthisClasstree` but there are also `addthisClasstwo` and `addthisClassone` in the `<div class="row demo"> .... </div>`

Comment: Do you want to add `addthisClasstree` and `addthisClasstwo` classes in the same element

Comment: There are tree radio button. id's `checked`, `checked1`, `checked2` . When you checked `id="checked"` then it need to be add `addthisClassone` from `checkedWrap`. Or when you checked `id="checked1"` then it need to be add `addthisClasstwo` from `checkedWrap`. Same think is for `id="checked2"`